# TridionSiteMapProvider with DD4T

Tags: 2011, dd4t

For using TridionSitemapProvider for navigation, one need to have a TBB (for logic dependant requirments). Now, the TridionSiteMapProvider (from DD4T.MVC Project) which needs to be activated in web.config (similar to handler/module in .net, i guess), but do we need to have a router configuration for calling controller/actions or any abstact methods (PRE/POST) need to be used?Do we need a partial view for this? What will be the model then? How and where (Controller/Model/View) this needs to be invoked and used?

Please help me understanding the flow and share your valuable ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to write a controller or partial views to write out the navigation. The typical approach is to write a 'MenuHelper' which you can then call from the Razor views.

The idea is explained here: http://www.squarewidget.com/Render-HTML-for-Menu-in-MVC-3-Using-SiteMapProvider.

Comment: Many Thanks Quirijn, for the reply. Could you please tell me how TridionSiteMap Provider fits in here? (something like in "http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/642/navigation-with-dd4t-and-mvc" or "https://code.google.com/p/dynamic-delivery-4-tridion/source/browse/trunk/dotnet/DD4T.Mvc/Providers/TridionSiteMapProvider.cs").

Comment: Please correct me if i am wrong, as in the shared link in the MenuHelper Class's function in place of "SiteMap.RootNode", i need to use the TridionSiteMapProvider Class's RootNode Function which returns a sitemap node. Is this work like this?